# Is there generalization for gamma function?

Tags: gamma-function, arithmetic-progressions

In Euler's "Differential calculus" we can find gamma function, as special case of interpolation of production, which factors formed by arithmetic progression:
$$f(a,b,w)=a^w\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a+nb)^{1-w}(a+(n+1)+b)^w}{a+b(n+w)}$$
So we can say, that
$$f(1,1,w)=\Gamma(1+w)$$
From that he find:
$$f(1,1,\frac{1}{2})=\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
$$f(1,2,\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
Last result can be expressed as interpolation for odd double factorial. Also using this function we can have any $n$-th factorials.

Can we call this function as generalization for $\Gamma(z)$? Is there any very well known function, which have the same character?

If I made some mistakes, sorry for my English.